# WPF: How do I know if Binding RelativeSource found an ancestor

Tags: wpf, data-binding, relativesource

I'm using the binding `RelativeSource` with the `FindAncestor` Mode but the binding is not working. How do I debug and see if It is able to find the ancestor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf)

EDIT: you can of course use the [usual debugging mechanisms](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405024839/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486), but I like Snoop the best. You can navigate to your control and if your binding failed it tells you so

Answer (score 4):

Or you can set PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel on the binding.
If you are using VS2010 remember to set the Data binding value in Options->Debugging->Output Window

Answer (score 1):

I use [WPF Inspector](https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/), it's a nice free tools for debugging WPF application in XAML level.